# Using Flask with subdomain breaks Google Task Queue routing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-tasks

I set SERVER_NAME in my Flask app to start using subdomains so I can have e.g. frontend and backend on two different subdomains:

- frontend.domain.com
- backend.domain.com

I set Flask like this:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'domain.com'
app.url_map.default_subdomain = "frontend"
```

The app is published using Google App Engine, everything works fine, except the default App Engine domain  `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com` now returns a 404 because I understand Flask is not recognising any matching route.

I thought it was fine since I never used `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com`, now I know I was wrong...

`https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com` is used by Google Task Cloud to route tasks and e.g. `myapp.ey.r.appspot.com/my_task_worker`, which is called by Cloud Tasks `create_task`, now hits a Not Found 404 while it worked before I set `SERVER_NAME`

How do I fix this? Do I have to hardcode `myapp.ey.r.appspot.com` in my Flask app somehow?

Here's an extract of my app.yaml, adapted:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
  
env_variables:
  DEBUG: False
  
  SERVER_NAME: 'domain.com'
  DEFAULT_SUBDOMAIN: 'frontend'
  
  GCP_PROJECT: 'myapp'
  CLOUD_TASK_LOCATION: 'europe-west3'
  CLOUD_TASK_QUEUE: 'default'

  GOOGLE_CLOUD_PLATFORM_API_KEY: 'xxxxxxxx'

  ...
```

Comment: could you edit your question and add your `app.yaml` ?

Comment: @Emmanuel, `app.yaml` added, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to hardcode myapp.ey.r.appspot.com in my Flask app somehow?

Yes. The problem here is that you're managing the redirection from your App instead of leaving App engine to do it. Although this isn't a bad practice by its own, it leaves many of the App Engine features out and most important, as you already mentioned, other GCP products like Cloud Tasks expect a specific behaviour in order to work properly.

> How do I fix this?

Under your current architecture you would have to add a routing to the default URL, however as far as I know Flask doesn't allow to route more than one domain, so you would have to switch the 'SERVER_NAME' to the default app engine or change into something like Django that supports multiple domains.

My suggestion is to [map](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app) your subdomains to App Engine services (one for your frontend and one for your backend) and leave the routing to GCP (and remove the 'SERVER_NAME'). You can make use of the [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) to do the routing, you can for example create the next routes:

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "myapp.ey.r.appspot.com/*"
    service: default

  - url: "frontend.domain.com/*"
    service: frontend

  - url: "backend.domain.com/*"
    service: backend
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, makes sense. This implies splitting a single Flask app into one-per-service, meaning I have to take care of making these communicate with each other and use common resources like external API clients etc. E.g. _backend_'s `url_for` wouldn't be able anymore to refer to _default_'s routes. I'd better stick to `domain.com/frontend` instead of `frontend.domain.com`...

Comment: If you're sharing resources that would make the frontend and backend dependent of each other then mapping them on the same domain and just splitting the access  with a URL ( domain.com/frontend) is the better choice and doing that wouldn't even require a `dispatch.yaml` file and everything can be done through the routing of your `app.yaml` file